# MySQL Fiddle syntax error when table name contains a space

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a schema for class but I get this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL, Apartment                  INTEGER                            NULL, City  ' at line 4.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER PIZZA ORDER NUMBER(
Last_Name                  VARCHAR(25)     PRIMARY KEY    NOT NULL,
First_Name                 VARCHAR(25)                    NOT NULL,
Street                     VARCHAR                            NULL,
Apartment                  INTEGER                            NULL,
City                       VARCHAR                            NULL,
State                      VARCHAR(2)                     NOT NULL,
Zip_Code                   INTEGER(5)                     NOT NULL,   
Home_Phone                 INTEGER(10)                    NOT NULL,
Mobile_Phone               INTEGER(10)                    NOT NULL,
Other_Phone                INTEGER(10)                    NOT NULL,
QTY_of_Pizzas              INTEGER                        NOT NULL,
Special_Handling_Notes     VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_ID                   INTEGER                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Name                 VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Description          VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Size                 VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Price                INTEGER                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Photo_URL            VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Order_Timestamp      INTEGER                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Order_ID             INTEGER                        NOT NULL,
);
CREATE TABLE PIZZA TABLE(
Pizza_ID                   INTEGER          NOT NULL   PRIMARY KEY, 
Pizza_Name                 VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Description          VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Size                 VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Price                INTEGER                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Photo_URL            VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
);
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER PIZZA TABLE(
Pizza_Order_ID             INTEGER          PRIMARY KEY   NOT NULL,
Pizza_Order_Timestamp      INTEGER                        NOT NULL,
QTY_of_Pizzas              INTEGER                        NOT NULL,
Special_Notes              VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
Last_Name                  VARCHAR(25)                    NOT NULL,
First_Name                 VARCHAR(25)                    NOT NULL,
Street                     VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
Apartment                  VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
City                       VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
State                      VARCHAR(2)                     NOT NULL,
ZIP                        INTEGER(5)                     NOT NULL,
Home_Phone                 INTEGER(10)                    NOT NULL,
Mobile_Phone               INTEGER(10)                    NOT NULL,
Other_Phone                INTEGER(10)                    NOT NULL,
Pizza_ID                   INTEGER                        NOT NULL,
);
CREATE TABLE PIZZA TABLE(
Pizza_ID                   INTEGER         PRIMARY KEY    NOT NULL,
Pizza_Name                 VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Description          VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Size                 VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Price                INTEGER                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Photo_URL            VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
);
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER TABLE(
Customer_ID                INTEGER        PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL.
Last_Name                  VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
First_Name                 VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
Street                     VARCHAR                            NULL
Apartment                  INTEGER                            NULL,
City                       VARCHAR                            NULL,
State                      VARCHAR(2)                     NOT NULL,
ZIP                        INTEGER(5)                     NOT NULL,
Home_Phone                 INTEGER(10)                    NOT NULL,  
Mobile_Phone               INTEGER(10)                    NOT NULL,
Other_Phone                INTEGER(10)                    NOT NULL,
);
CREATE TABLE PIZZA ORDER TABLE(
Pizza_Order_ID             INTEGER          PRIMARY KEY   NOT NULL,
Pizza_ID                   INTEGER                        NOT NULL,
Customer_ID                INTEGER                        NOT NULL,
QTY_of_Pizzas              INTEGER                        NOT NULL,
Special_Notes              VARCHAR                        NOT NULL,
Pizza_Order_Timestamp      INTEGER                        NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: Insert the missing comma before `Apartment`.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER PIZZA ORDER NUMBER`? The table has 4 names?

Answer (score 0):

- There are two tables have the same name.
- Some "," using "." to spilt.
- Missing "," to spilt
- Table name contain space?

I think if you fix the above problem, it would be fine.